# border that encapsulates textblocks

Tags: wpf

I am not sure if this is possible in wpf or not but, lets say I have multiple textblocks and other controls in a grid on a page

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  FontSize="30" 
Text="Station" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65.2,0,0,3"  
VerticalAlignment="top" Width="104" Height="47" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50.2,2,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
Width="120" Height="22" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Text="Date"  FontSize="30" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59.8,0,0,5"  VerticalAlignment="top" 
Height="45" Width="72" />
    <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="59.8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  
RenderTransformOrigin="1.078,0.417" Height="24" Width="102" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Item"  FontSize="30" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59.8,0,0,5"  VerticalAlignment="top" 
Height="45" Width="72" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="UoM" FontSize="30" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59.8,0,0,5" VerticalAlignment="top" 
Height="45" Width="72" />
...
```

Is there a way to encapsulate those controls and have them in a border that stays at the top of my screen, even when the textboxes underneath the code is scrolled down.  I.e something similar to an HTML header that stays at the top of the screen when you scroll down the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a scrollviewer for your controls on the bottom and let the grid take care of the static positioning.

Something like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border>
        <!-- Your static header here -->
    </Border>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Your scrolling content here -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```